# SQL query pulling data Only closest to todays date

Tags: sql, excel

I am automating my weekly/monthly projects through Excel 2016's get data from Microsoft Query and I need to only pull data from the 'currentFileDate' column that is closest to 'GetDate' function.

The 'CurrentFileDate' information is updated at practically random intervals due to pulls from other company databases failing frequently so setting the getdate function to only look back a week or a few days will not work.

Comment: So, some clarification, please: 1) Is currentFileDate a field in the DB you're querying? 2) Do you need any data besides that column from that DB? 3) What DB technology is the DB you're querying? 4) Can you describe the logic you're trying to use on that column? Are you just looking for the latest currentFileDate or something else?

Comment: 1. currentFileDate is a field in the DB that I'm querying.
2. I am pulling other data based on the date, yes.  It's more like I'm filtering out results that aren't closest to todays date (getdate()).
3. I querry off of it using SQL server 2014 if that helps.
4. currently my code looks like this:

use [BCADataSQL ]

Select 
aa.WarehouseCode,
aa.CoopModel,

aa.LostSalesDate


from tools.tblAceLostSalesArticle AA



where aa.lostsalesdate < GETDATE() and
aa.vendornumber = 10712

Comment: So, what you're trying to do is to replace that GETDATE() portion (i.e. the part that filters to the current date)), right? So, if you don't want to compare against the current date, what do you want to compare against?